# Why i'm getting background color in this (rgb(204, 204, 204) none repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box border-box) format?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have `LI` where i have given a `background-color: #ccc;`, basically i want to get background color in variable, Now i'm getting this `rgb(204, 204, 204) none repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box border-box` format in variable but i want this `rgb(204, 204, 204)` format, what is wrong in this code?

What i tried:-

```js
$('.response-box').on('click', '.color-box ul li', function() {
  var colorBoxListBgColor = $(this).css('background');
  console.log(colorBoxListBgColor);
});
```

```css
.color-box ul li {
  background-color: #ccc;
  color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="response-box">
  <div class="color-box">
    <ul>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Click on `LI` to check output in console.

Answer will be appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `.css('backgroundColor')` instead of `.css('background')`, if you just want the color, but not the other parts of the background:

```js
$('.response-box').on('click', '.color-box ul li', function() {
  console.log($(this).css('backgroundColor'));
});
```

```css
.color-box ul li {
  background-color: #ccc;
  color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="response-box">
  <div class="color-box">
    <ul>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```